# How to copy part of an image to a specific section in another image? (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, image, image-processing, copy-paste

I'm looking to copy a section of one image onto a specific section of another image. I'm using Visual Studio and VB.net, as I'm more familiar with that language than any other.

My initial thought was that you could create a bitmap with the selected contents of the first image, and then sort of "paste" that bitmap onto a specified section of the second image. I could be completely off here.

For example: The first image is 70x70 and I want to copy a 32x32 portion drawing my rectangle (or in this case, square) from point (12, 8) to point (43, 39). I then want to copy the contents of this rectangle to a point on the second image, overwriting whatever might already be there. The second image is 400x300 and I want to "paste" the selection from the first image at point (23x50), covering the area from point (23, 50) to point (54, 81).

This is just a hobby project that I work on in my spare time, so I may only be able to answer a couple time a day or a couple times an hour based on what else is going on. Thanks to everyone for the patience and help. It is appreciated.

Comment: do research on the graphics methods. That contains a method to paint part of an image on another with clipping scaling etc.

Comment: Sounds a bit like watermarking. Do research.  Add Code. Ask Question,

Comment: @Trevor I've read up on graphics methods from the MSDN articles and some Google results, but it seems like all I can do create lines and such on an already existing image. Almost like using Paint through code. I feel like there is a way to do what I'm looking for with the graphics methods. I just can't find how to do it. Is there a way to hold the pixels from a rectangle on one image and then copy them to a rectangle on another image with graphics methods?

Comment: DrawImage method is what you want... https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Drawing.Graphics.DrawImage);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.0);k(DevLang-VB)&rd=true

Comment: @Trevor Thanks! That got it! It took me a while to figure out how to make it work. Would you like to make this an official answer so I can give you the proper credit?

Comment: @ZeverMX .. Done...